# How to check if you clicked the close button on the window? (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, windows, winapi

I just want to ask what command in Ruby allows you to check if an application made in Ruby or running application is about to be closed? For example, I have an executable file that i ran and I clicked the close button on the window. I want to make a pop up of a dialog that says "you are about to close". Once you pressed the OK button, the window finally closes.

How can you do this in Ruby?

Comment: The user just expressed their desire to close a window. What insight do you hope to gain from asking them again? While there may be reasonable use-cases to get notified about a window being closed, this is not one of them.

Comment: There is a big reason why I want to do this. Before closing the window, I am intending to show something important, a notification and opening a certain window that shows something. I just want to ask the user to be indicated that if they are sure they wanna close the window or not. Sometimes, accidental close buttons are made by users.

Comment: It depends on what framework you are using for your GUI, or are you talking in the context of a web application (with something like Rails or Sinatra)?

Comment: I am using a program that runs Ruby code. Basically, something like Shoes (http://shoesrb.com/) for example. The only way I can think of for having this made is by accessing the Win32 applications that checks the CLose Button from the Window and Detect it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how things work in Ruby, but in general, on Windows, when a window receives a request to close, its window procedure receives a  [`WM_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-close) message.  This is the place to display prompts to the user.  If the app then wants to block the window from closing (because the user wants to reject it, etc), the app can simply skip destroying the window, and not pass the message on to the default message handler (`DefWindowProc()`).

In the case where the user clicks on the window's close button, or chooses the "Close" option from the window's pop-up system menu, or presses <kbd>ALT-F4</kbd> while the window is in focus, the window receives a [`WM_SYSCOMMAND(SC_CLOSE)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/menurc/wm-syscommand) message, and if the message is passed on to the default message handler, the window then receives the `WM_CLOSE` message.

Take that information and translate it to Ruby as needed.