# Which function in winapi check whether the button is closing the console?

Tags: c++, function, winapi, button, console

I want the message to be displayed if you press button close console
Which function in winapi check whether the button is closing the console?

Comment: There's no such function, neither with the c or the c++ standard libraries. You might need to intercept your terminal program's control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, a console app can use [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolectrlhandler) to catch `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` notifications:

> A signal that the system sends to all processes attached to a console when the user closes the console (either by clicking **Close** on the console window's window menu, or by clicking the **End Task** button command from Task Manager)

For example:

```
BOOL WINAPI MyHandlerRoutine(DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
    if (dwCtrlType == CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
    {
       //...
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(&MyHandlerRoutine, TRUE);
    //...
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(&MyHandlerRoutine, FALSE);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used it and dont work if (!SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE)CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, FALSE)) {
  MessageBoxA(NULL, "NO", "Text", 0);
 }

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to.  The 1st parameter must be a **pointer to a function** that will receive the notifications. I have updated my answer to include an example

Comment: @ВениаминНиколаевич if you hope to keep Windows from terminating your process this way your hope is in vain.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau which function used for window app?

Comment: @ВениаминНиколаевич see https://stackoverflow.com/a/52211980/65863

Comment: @Remy Lebeau how I can contact you? Where can I write a private message to you?